# How to order SQL query by largest string array sizes?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Background**
I'm quite new to SQL so apologies if I come off ignorant. After reading through some related threads I am still confused.

I got the data from a Firestore export whose endpoint was a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I created a table from the bucket data in BigQuery.

### **Question**

I want to order the query by the column that has `bucketIds`, which is an `array<string>` from largest to smallest. And display the corresponding title of that row (`bucketTitle`).

```
SELECT  bucketTitle, bucketIds
FROM table 
ORDER BY bucketIds DESC
LIMIT 100
```

### **Problems / Errors**

Error:
`ORDER BY does not support expressions of type ARRAY<STRING>`

If I use the aggregate function `COUNT()` on the array like this:

```
SELECT  bucketTitle, bucketIds
FROM table 
ORDER BY COUNT(bucketIds) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I receive this error:
`The ORDER BY clause only allows aggregation if GROUP BY or SELECT list aggregation is present at`

If I group the query by the title like

```
SELECT  bucketTitle, bucketIds
FROM table
GROUP BY bucketTitle
ORDER BY COUNT(bucketIds) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Then it throws: `SELECT list expression references column bucketIds which is neither grouped nor aggregated at`

And if I try to include `bucketIds` in the grouping like

```
GROUP BY bucketTitle, COUNT(bucketIds)
```

The error states: `Aggregate function COUNT not allowed in GROUP BY at`
However, you are also not allowed to include columns of type array in `GROUP BY`

Comment: array_length() https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length

Comment: "from largest to smallest" what does this mean?  The number of elements in the array?  The total length of the strings?  Some alphabetical or other ordering?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the critique. I will have more precise questions in the future. To answer your questions, I wanted to order by the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below Query:-

```
SELECT  bucketTitle, bucketIds
FROM table 
ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(bucketIds) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: This query is ordered properly. However, how can I display the count of elements instead of the array's data?

Comment: You can use (SELECT COUNT(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;) to display the count of elements.